# Converting from Mat To Bitmap keeping the resolution intact

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

I am using tess-two(android port of Tesseract) for OCR. I am using OpenCV to convert to grayscale and apply adaptive thresholding. The result is excellent. The problem is the resolution. When I convert the Mat to bitmap, the file size drops from 315 kb to 12kb. The resultant output of Tesseract is garbage. Is there any way to keep the resolution of the image intact while using Utils.matToBitmap(). If not possible, then a workaround would be helpful. Here is my code:

```
    Mat tmp = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat source = new Mat(tmp.rows(), tmp.cols(), tmp.type());
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, source, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    //Adaptive Threshold
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(source, source, new Size(3, 3), 0);
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(source, source, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
            Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 4);

    Utils.matToBitmap(source, bitmap);
```

Comment: Your image is initially a 3 channel BGR image (note that OpenCV stores internally the images as BGR, not RGB, so you should use COLOR_BGR2GRAY), but what you're saving is a 1 channel grayscale (binary in this case) image. Try saving a 3 channel image as bitmap: `Imgproc.cvtColor(source, source, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR); Utils.matToBitmap(source, bitmap);`

Comment: But I need a binary image for Tesseract. What does COLOR_GRAY2BGR do?

Comment: The image is still binary, but 3 channel. Give it a try an check if results are better or not

Comment: nope...no significant change.

Comment: Wierd, in this code there isn't anything that affects resolution...

Comment: @Miki...I know this should  be a different question but...is there any other means by which I can improve the accuracy of OCR using openCV.

Comment: Pre-processing to get a clean image is the most important step. If you have a single font, or a limited character set, you can retrain tesseract specifically, or limit the set of characters (in the Init, if I remember correctly)

Comment: Actually I am OCR'ing bills and receipts....I have tried turning off dictionary...I have trained almost 5 fonts...but clarity eludes. The character set cannot be limited. Have tried giving custom word-list too.

Comment: Well, you seem to be on the right track. There's nothing more I can tell you. Try posting some images, showing the problems you have. Probably with a more detailed question you'll get more detailed answers